# setting button property in WPF C# application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am a beginner in C#. I was trying to set some properties to my button in my visual C# WPF application using the following xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Panel.ZIndex="1" Content="Button" Height="37" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="378,12,38,262" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="87" >
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="buttonStyle">
                <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Gray"/>
                <Setter Property="Button.Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Button.FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS"/>
            </Style>
        </Button.Resources>
    </Button>

    <Image Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="image1">
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage UriSource="images.jpg"></BitmapImage>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

But the Button.Resource has no effect on the style of the button. Can anyone please tell me the problem in this

Comment: Look more into Styles and Triggers with WPF.

Comment: I read "Comic Sans MS". :( :( :( :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<Button Panel.ZIndex="1" Content="Button" Height="37" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Margin="378,12,38,262" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width
```

with

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource buttonStyle}" Panel.ZIndex="1"
Content="Button" Margin ="169,84,34,0" Name="button1" Height="23"
VerticalAlignment="Top">
```

Answer (score 1):

You create explicit `Button` style but you don't use it anywhere. You can either set these values directly against button

```
<Button ... Background="Gray" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS"/>
```

or, if you want to create explicit `Style`, as you do, you need to use it on your `Button`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
       <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
           <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
           <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS"/>
       </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Button ... Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

or you can create implicit style, that will automatically apply to child `Button` controls in current visual tree

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
           <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
           <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS"/>
       </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Button .../>
</Grid>
```

or create `Style` just for that `Button`

```
<Button>
   <Button.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
         <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS"/>
      </Style>
   </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" 
               TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Gray"/>
            <Setter Property="Button.Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Button.FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Panel.ZIndex="1" Content="Button" Height="37" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="378,12,38,262" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Width="87" >
        </Button>
        <Image Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="image1">
        </Image>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this way:

```
        <Button Panel.ZIndex="1" Content="Button" Height="37" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            Margin="378,12,38,262" x:Name="button1" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="87" 
            Background="Gray" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" />
```